# Solving for the principal value of a trigonometric equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The question is as follows:

$$3{\tan}^2(2x)-1=0.$$ Solve for $x$.

What steps should I take to solve? The squaring is really throwing me off.

Comment: What have you tried? This should just be a fairly straightforward manipulation. Remember that the solutions to $x^2=y$ are $\sqrt{y}$ and $-\sqrt{y}$.

Comment: I removed the trig so I could factor, so I had 6x^2-1. The solutions to this are plus or minus 0.408. I've plugged it back in, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Well,
$$3 \tan^2(2x) - 1 = 0 \\ \tan^2(2x) = \frac{1}{3} \\ \tan(2x) = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}.$$
Can you take it from there?

Comment: Oh, I feel silly now. Thanks, I got it!

Comment: Nice, John is answering John :)

Comment: It was my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\tan^22x}1=\frac13$$

Applying by [Componendo and dividendo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Componendo_and_dividendo),

$$\frac{1-\tan^22x}{1+\tan^22x}=\frac{3-1}{3+1}$$

$$\implies \cos4x=\frac12=\cos\frac\pi3\implies4x=2n\pi\pm\frac\pi3$$ where $n$ is any integer